# Multiple Instagram Streams on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, instagram, instagram-api

I was wondering if anyone could answer this question.

I am in need of a plugin that can handle multiple Instagram accounts to display individually on separate pages.

This is for a client that needs their employees to have their own feed on their profile pages.

I need to know if this is actually possible before looking further into it... any help would be appreciated.

The idea would be to embed a stream in a page via a shortcode with the account id or url or something like that...

Regards,

Felixius

Answer (score 1):

Below plugin useful for you.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/instagram-feed/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-instagram-feed/

Please try it and let me know.

Comment: That second link looks promising!